# Multiple background define a size css

Tags: html, css, background

How can I define the width for only the second background?

```
background: url(../images/Logo1.png) bottom no-repeat , url(../images/Logo_2.png)  98% 100% no-repeat white !important;
background-attachment:fixed !important;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You might want to provide some HTML and some more CSS to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: do you mean the _size_ ?

Comment: #home{
 background: url(../images/Logo1.png) bottom no-repeat , url(../images/Logo2.png)  98% 100% no-repeat white !important;
 background-attachment:fixed !important;
}                                                                                                                                                                                  <section id="home">
</section>                                                                                                                 I would like to define the size (width and height) of the second image.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(../images/Logo1.png) bottom no-repeat, url(../images/Logo_2.png) 98% 100% / WIDTH HEIGHT no-repeat white !important;
background-attachment:fixed !important;
```

Where I have put `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` is where you can set the size of that image.

Before the forward slash is `background-position` after is `background-size`.